# change configure -prefix in apache 2.2.18 installation linux

Tags: linux, apache-2.2, uninstall, configuration

I have installed apache2.2.18 on my linux server.

However, while configuring it using ***./configure –prefix=PREFIX*** command i gave a wrong prefix. I noticed it after running ***make install*** command as files got installed at wrong folder. I wanted to install them inside a subfolder in the given path.

Is there a direct way to change the prefix again to appropriate path? Am I required to reinstall it again? If yes, how as ***make uninstall*** does not work?

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: what is the error you get when doing make uninstall?

Answer (score 1):

If you can not use sudo, you can't start any service - because starting service require port binding.

Answer (score 1):

There is no `make uninstall` for apache. You will need to manually find and delete all the files copied by your `make install` command, most likely inside the 'PREFIX' path you specified. (If you ran `make install` as non-root user, and your 'PREFIX' was something like /usr, then chances are nothing actually got installed anyway.)

For future, use this handy tool instead of 'make install':

```
checkinstall
```

This will create an rpm or pkg file suitable for your package manager, and the package can be uninstalled if needed.